# Will a disconnected udp socket still receive traffic from a port that another socket is connected to?

Tags: c, udp

I'm trying to write a server/client pair to run over udp, and the only way i've been able to get it going is having the server aware of the client's ip and port before the connection starts. My new design involves waiting for a packet to come in, recording the sender address, forking to a child process (the parent loops around and continues listening), which then `connect's` to the client the transmitted the packet. The child should then only receive packets from the associated client, but the documentation is unclear is the parent socket will continue receive traffic from that client. I'm working on a program to try it, but i figured i could ask the question at the same time.

**EDIT:** It seems that when the child's socket is `connected'd` it will connect the parent's socket too.

Comment: I do not think you understand what the UDP protocol is. It's designed to be a **connectionless** protocol.

Comment: @JacobPollack From the `connect(2)` man-page: "If the socket sockfd is of type SOCK_DGRAM then addr is the address to which datagrams are sent by default, and the only address from which datagrams are received."

Comment: The question is, are packets from `addr` then diverted from the socket in the parent, which is bound to the same port?

Comment: "I'm working on a program to try it, but i figured i could ask the question at the same time." This is exactly what [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) is all about, don't just ask, but try and ask if you get stuck.

Comment: I asked the question because if someone could answer it before i complete my experiment i'd have saved time, and considering it seems like a fairly simple "yes or no" question i didn't think i was wasting anyone else's time.

Comment: You're going to have to keep testing. One would imagine that an inherited socket is still the *same* socket, so connecting/disconnecting it will affect both the parent and the child, but you will have to test. You will also have to test whether receiving in both the parent and child works *regardless* of whether one disconnects it or not. I suggest that these two issues are completely independent.

Comment: I've answered the question myself, but i don't appreciate the condescending attitude of some of the people here.

Answer (score 1):

UDP protocol does not operate connections, it's a connection-less protocol. It is enough for one side to listen and other side to just send datagrams for data channel to work.

On the question (sorry, didn't got the point before): forking is not the way out when working with UDP. Connection-based protocols are widely used with that technique. That is possible because:

- you can fork right after `listen()`
- the first process accepts connection works with it (and only that process posesses the newly created connected socket.

When you work with UDP you don't have such gap (as before `accept()` with TCP) to know when exactly to fork (especially when you have intensive datagram flow).

So, when you design UDP service, you need either

- use non-blocking I/O with event loop or
- design threaded solution.

Comment: But you can use the `connect` function with a udp socket. From the `connect(2)` man-page: "If  the socket sockfd is of type SOCK_DGRAM then addr is the address to which datagrams are sent by default, and the only  address  from  which datagrams  are  received."

Comment: @RobbieMckennie, it serves as a restriction, but still does not have any relation to a `connection` term. This only means that you can use `send` after connect, because `sendto` always requires passing address of remote host

Comment: Okay, but that still doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Are you saying that anything i do to the socket in the child process will have no effect on what the socket in the parent process does?

Comment: @RobbieMckennie, when you fork a process, its resources are forked too, so you will get a packet in child process or in parent process (it depends on who first runs recv)